# A question about polynomials

Tags: polynomials

How can we prove that the following expression is a polynomial?
$$
  \frac{1-x^{2^{n-1}}}{1-x}
$$
I've asked this question just for learning the ways different from using

$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+···+x^{n-1})$.

Comment: You need to show that $(1-x)$ divides $(1-x^{2^{n-1}})$ for any $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even easier, $1-1^{2^{n-1}}=0$, so $1-x^{2^{n-1}}=(x-1)P(x)$ for some polynomial $P$. We don't need a constructive solution ;)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: for any $k\in\Bbb N$ we have $1-x^k=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{k-1})$.

Comment: Even easier, $1-1^{2^{n-1}}=0$, so $1-x^{2^{n-1}}=(x-1)P(x)$ for some polynomial $P$. We don't need a constructive solution ;)

Comment: @feynman Not quite - in your case $k=2^{n-1}$, so last exponent would be $2^{n-1}-1$.

Comment: @Cody Johnson Your comment is a great perspective on this question. You should turn that into an answer!

Comment: Did I do it correctly? Sorry, I'm new to this website

Comment: @CodyJohnson Yes, you did it correctly: you are free to comment on answers. But if your comment entails a significantly different and interesting view on the problem at hand, sometimes someone comes along to ask you to write an answer about it (by using the box below). Right now, this is no longer possible for this question, since it is been labeled as duplicate. Maybe next time;)

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\forall m\in \mathbb{N}, 1-x^m=(1-x)(1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1})$$

Just take $m=2^{n-1}$ and you're done